# Rails - Polymorphic Association to Create Different Profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

Attempting to make it so that when a user is created, based on whether they select to be a student or a corporate, rails will create that user either a student profile or a corporate profile.

Ive tried to set it up using Polymorphic associations however cant figure out how to generate the profile at the model layer based on what is selected in the view.

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_secure_password 

  has_one :student_profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :corporate_profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :searches, dependent: :destroy


  #attr_accessor :profile_type - removed due to Rails 4, pushed strong params in controller

  before_create :create_profile

      def create_profile
        if profile_type == 1
          build_student_profile
        else
          build_corporate_profile
        end
      end
 end
```

Student and Corporate Profiles

```
class CorporateProfile < ActiveRecord::Base # or possibly inherit from ActiveRecord::Base if not using inheritance

  belongs_to :user

end

class StudentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base # or possibly inherit from ActiveRecord::Base if not using inheritance

  belongs_to :user

end
```

**View**

Here i have two radio buttons to decide which user type on the sign up form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@user) do |f| %>

            <div class="field">
              <%= f.form_group :gender, label: { text: "Gender" }, help: "Are you a corporate or a student?" do %>
              <p></p>
                  <%= f.radio_button :profileable, 1, label: "Student",   inline: true %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :profileable, 2, label: "Corporate", inline: true %>
                <% end %>
          </div>
```

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def index
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 5).includes(:profile)
  end

  def show
  if params[:id] 
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      # .includes(:profile)
    else 
      @user = current_user
    end
    @searches = Search.where(user_id: @user).includes(:state, city: [:profile])
  end


  def new
    @user = User.new
    #@corporateprofile = Corporateprofile.new

  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to widgets_index_path
    else
      redirect to '/signup'
    end
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :profile_type)
  end

end
```

And there is no passing code on the controller (as im stuck on that). Any better suggestion or ways to fix this would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you want to rename your profile classes to StudentProfile and CorporateProfile. This will necessitate running migrations to change your table names too.

The answer to this question depends on how different you want StudentProfile and CorporateProfile to be. If they are completely different or even mostly different, make them separate classes. If they are mostly the same (in other words, they share many of the same methods) you should create a Profile (or UserProfile) model and have StudentProfile and CorporateProfile inherit from this model.

As for implementation, it should look something like this:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :student_profile
  has_one :corporate_profile

  attr_accessor :profileable #probably change this to profile_type. Using attr_accessible because we want to use it during creation, but no need to save it on the user model, although it may not be a bad idea to create a column for user model and save this value.

  before_create :create_profile

  def create_profile
    if profileable == 1
      build_student_profile
    else
      build_corporate_profile
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
# student_profile.rb
class StudentProfile < UserProfile # or possibly inherit from ActiveRecord::Base if not using inheritance
  belongs_to :user

  # other student profile stuff here
end
```

And corporate profile model would look the same as student profile.

Also, you should be using Rails 4 at this point, especially if you're learning and don't understand controllers and params, as this is pretty different between rails 3 and 4. No use in learning something that's outdated, right?

---

Edit: I should mention, I don't thing you're understanding rails polymorphism. A model should be polymorphic when it will belong to multiple models, *not* when it will have different subclasses.

For example, if your app has a Like model and something else like a Post model, and a user can like other users' profiles or posts, that might be a good candidate for polymorphism, because Like may belong to StudentProfiles or CorporateProfiles or Posts.

Comment: Ah appologies nick! I am using rails 4, and accidentally checked Rails - 3 as the tag, which means `attr_accessible' ias you know no longer works. I've moved the logic to the controller so that profile_type is part of the user params, but am getting errors with "UserProfile" being an uninitialized constant.

Comment: Oops, meant to put `attr_accessor` not `attr_accessible`. Edited now. If you're having trouble with your controller code, you should post that too, but it sounds like you haven't created a model yet for UserProfile.

Comment: aha, ok so I've updated my code with attr_accessor. Also note, I have decided not to implement UserProfile inheritance as the two profiles are completely different. My challenge is corporate profile is always being generated, not student profile.

Comment: got it!, my profile_type was set to string in the migrate file and not integer which was not allowing for it to pick up the model code. Cheers Nick, your a legend

Comment: Your answer is AN answer, not THE answer. When you say "I don't think you're understanding rails polymorphism" I think you're wrong. This is a good use case for having a polymorphic profile, which means it can be presented in many forms (have different attributes). This is well explained in this video, around minute 8: http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations